# Custom Annotation layout with label and image in ios

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotationview

When i click on mapview's pin,
I want to open an mkannotationview with custom layout having one image on left side and name of the person on right side..

How can i do this in ios?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What you have tried and problem you face??

Comment: lecture 15 (mapkit) gives you an example exactly for what you want https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-7-apps-for/id733644550

Comment: @CRDave Actually i've not started yet as i don't know from where to start.

Comment: So i need someone's help to start.

Comment: Searching internet is always good point to start : https://www.google.co.in/search?q=mapkit+custom+annotation+view&oq=mkmapkit+custom+ann&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.6412j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Ask question here only when u don't find any thing after searching or not able to do any thing after many afford. Don't ask every question which pop out in our mind. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: i'm having image for annotation layout but stackoverflow doesn't allow me to upload..so it may happen that you could not get what i mean exactly...

Comment: Start with the documentation and the sample apps: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Thanks @Anna.This tutorial help me to implement makannotation in MKMapview.Now its working as expected.